# How to upgrade packages when you've used os-hardening cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I have a server managed with chef. I have applied the [https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/os-hardening] cookbook and the [https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv] cookbook.

Everything works fine after the first run where I install ruby 2.4.1

If I later install ruby 2.4.2 I am unable to run ruby due to file permission errors.

At the terminal when I run `ruby -v` I get a `rbenv: ruby: command not found`

I am pretty sure this is because of the way the os-hardening cookbook changes file system permissions and I probably need to configure it in some way, but I can't find any documentation for how to do this.

Comment: Look at `id` and `$PATH`. Verify that that user can run the executable in question. The commands `which` and `rbenv install` may prove helpful.

Comment: It's definitely a permissions issue. The directory 2.4.2 installs to only has 750 permissions. (/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.4.2). I know I can make it work with chmod, but I'm trying to understand how to correctly use this cookbook.

Comment: You mentioned it did `chmod g+rx 2.4.2/`, which suggests a group membership issue. The output of `id` will show what groups you're in. Perhaps you want to edit /etc/group to place that user in the directory's group. Or perhaps `rbenv_script` needs a "group" argument.

Comment: Owner and group on 2.4.2 are root, I don't think I'd want to put an application user in the root group though. I could change the group of the directory, but the rbenv cookbook doesn't seem to have an option to do that which makes me think that's not a very typical thing to do?

Comment: There is no specific answer to this question other than to manually diagnose how the two are interacting incorrectly and fix one or the other. Chef has no role here other than it is doing what you told it to.